# Class creation in object oriented PHP

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

```
  <?php
 // Selects 1
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mainInfo WHERE type='1' ORDER BY name");
$stmt->execute();
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
$result_1 = $resultSet->fetch_all();

// Selects 2
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mainInfo WHERE type='2' ORDER BY name");
$stmt->execute();
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
$result_2 = $resultSet->fetch_all();

// Selects 3
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mainInfo WHERE type='3' ORDER BY name");
$stmt->execute();
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
$result_3 = $resultSet->fetch_all();
```

I have 3 sepperate select statements where only "type" changes.
the values that are returned are later used in other code.
can i make a class where there is only 1 statement for all 3 types and be 
used later in the :

```
<?php foreach($result_1 as $item){
    echo '
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="square">
          <input name="cb_id[]" class="checkBox" type="checkbox" 
    value="'.$item[0].'">
          <p>'.$item[0].' <br> ' . $item[1] .' <br> ' . $item[2] . 
    '$<br>Size: ' .$item[4] . ' MB</p>
        </div>
       </div>';}
  ?>

<?php foreach($result_2 as $item){
    echo '
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="square">
          <input name="cb_id[]" class="checkBox" type="checkbox" 
 value="'.$item[0].'">
          <p>'.$item[0].' <br> ' . $item[1] .' <br> ' . $item[2] . 
 '$<br>Weight: ' .$item[5] . ' KG</p>
        </div>
      </div>';}
  ?>

  <?php foreach($result_3 as $item){
      echo '
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="square">
            <input name="cb_id[]" class="checkBox" type="checkbox" 
   value="'.$item[0].'">
            <p>'.$item[0].' <br> ' . $item[1] .' <br> ' . $item[2] . 
   '$<br>Dim: ' .$item[6] . 'X' .$item[7] . 'X' .$item[8] . '</p>
          </div>
        </div>';}
    ?>
```

i am myself confused about this so any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not simply a function? Why a class?

Comment: I think a function would be prudent here. It takes `Type` as input and would be a parameter in your sql [so you could `bindparam`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Then you can just call the function and pass the type. That function **could** be a method inside a class, but without knowing your code, I couldn't guess what would make sense as a class here (perhaps a `maininfo` class?)

Comment: If you want to go via a class , then create a class file and create where you need to define a class and define a public function where you take input 1, 2, 3, ... and return the array which you need to catch from front-end and display in a table format .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach. using a loop:

```
$results = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mainInfo WHERE type='$i' ORDER BY name");
  $stmt->execute();
  $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
  array_push($results, $resultSet->fetch_all());
}
```

Second Approach. using function:

```
function returnResult($type){
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mainInfo WHERE type='$type' ORDER BY name");
  $stmt->execute();
  $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
  return $resultSet->fetch_all();
}
$result1 = returnResult(1);
$result2 = returnResult(2);
$result3 = returnResult(2);
```

third approach OO PHP

```
class Foo { 

  public function returnResult($type){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mainInfo WHERE type='$type' ORDER BY name");
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
    return $resultSet->fetch_all();)
  }
} 
$SomeObject = new Foo;
$result1 = $SomeObject->returnResult(1);
$result2 = $SomeObject->returnResult(2);
$result3 = $SomeObject->returnResult(3);
```

I did write the code here. Did not test it. If I were you I would use the first approach

PS. of course you have to specify $db in all three approaches.

Comment: third approach was what i was looking for, thank you for so quick answer